# How can I get all documents that were created by a certain user in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using Swift 4, Firebase Auth, Firebase Cloud Firestore.

I have a chat DB and a user DB. I am using phone authentication with Firebase and am saving the UID to store for each user in the user DB. For each chat DB, I am storing the current user's UID to allow a lookup to happen. It's here where I am stuck. Is there anyway I can get all chats from a specific user if the sender ID is a attribute to each document in the chat DB?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it's possible. But it's hard to be more concrete beyond that it'll look something like `var query = chatsRef.where("uid", "==", uid)`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out

```
func getChatsFromUser() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("chats").whereField("senderID", isEqualTo: String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid))
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                }
            }
    }
}
```